# How to make Travis CI to install Python dependencies declared in tests_require?

Tags: python, testing, travis-ci, setup.py

I have Python package with `setup.py`. It has regular dependencies declared in `install_requires` and development dependencies declared in `tests_require`, e.g. `flake8`.

I thought `pip install -e .` or running `python setup.py test` will also install my development dependencies and they'll be available. However, apparently they're not and I struggle to setup my Travis CI build right.

```
install:
  - "pip install -e ."
script:
  - "python setup.py test"
  - "flake8"
```

Build configured as above will fail, because `flake8` will not be found as a valid command. I also tried to invoke `flake8` from inside of the `python setup.py test` command (via `subprocess`), but also without success.

Also I hate the fact that `flake8` can't be easily made integral part of the `python setup.py test` command, but that's another story.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I prefer to keep most of the configuration in `tox.ini` and rely on it to install and run what is to be run. For testing I use `pytest` (the solution can be modified to use other testing frameworks easily).

Following files are used:

- `tox.ini`: automates the test
- `.travis.yml`: instructions for Travis
- `setup.py`: installation script to install the package to test
- `test_requirements.txt`: list of requirements for testing

## `tox.ini`

```
[tox]
envlist = py{26,27,33,34}

[testenv]
commands =
    py.test -sv tests []
deps =
    -rtest-requirements.txt
```

## `.travis.yml`

```
sudo: false
language: python
python:
    - 2.6
    - 2.7
    - 3.3
    - 3.4
install:
    - pip install tox-travis
script:
 - tox
```

## `test_requirements.txt`

Just ordinary requirements file whith what ever you need in there (e.g. `flake8`, `pytest` and other dependencies)

You may see sample at https://github.com/vlcinsky/awslogs/tree/pbr-setup.py

The fact it uses there `pbr`, `coverage` and `coverall` is not relevant to my answer (it works with or without pbr).

Comment: This is probably the best solution to date. FWIW, what I've also seen in the wild is to use `extras_require` in `setup.py` together with `pip install -e .[tests]`. It's also easy to keep it DRY and define test requirements as a separate list assigned to both `extras_require['tests']` and `tests_require`. (See e.g. my library https://github.com/honzajavorek/fiobank/ )

Answer (score 2):

The more direct answer is that `pip install` will not install `tests_require`, intentionally separating runtime requirements from test requirements. `python setup.py test` creates a virtualenv-like environment to run the tests in, un-doing this afterwards. `flake8` is thus unavailable once it is done.

Flake8 has [setuptools integration](https://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.4/setuptools.html) and also [integrates with pytest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-flake8) if you use that. pytest itself [also integrates with setuptools](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner).

Comment: `python setup.py test` is no longer recommended, in favor of using `tox`

Comment: True as that may be, I’m answering the question as asked.